# How can I be sure that my auido isn't down sampled?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I want to play audio without downsampling or without any resampling? How can I do that? My audio files are 192kHz and 32 bits. I wan to play those music files without losing quality. My DAC supports that quality. I use Music on Console as my music player and its output is sent to ALSA. Does ALSA resample audio or should I switch to PulseAudio or OSS? And does `pacmd info` print the properties that's sent to the DAC or does it print the file properties?

Output of pacmd list:

> index: 79   driver: <protocol-native.c>     flags:      state: RUNNING
> sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>    volume:
> front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00
> dB
> balance 0.00    muted: no   current latency: 253.67 ms  requested latency: 75.00 ms     sample spec: s16le 2ch 192000Hz     channel
> map: front-left,front-right
> Stereo     resample method: speex-float-1  module: 9   client: 46 <ALSA plug-in [mocp]>    properties:         media.name = "ALSA
> Playback"         application.name = "ALSA plug-in [mocp]"
> native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
> native-protocol.version = "34"      application.process.id = "22080"
> application.process.user = "archie"         application.process.host =
> "PC"      application.process.binary = "mocp"         application.language =
> "en_US.UTF-8"         window.x11.display = ":0"
> application.process.machine_id = "a89655b594a2465f882377c2c49da4be"
> application.process.session_id = "1"        module-stream-restore.id =
> "sink-input-by-application-name:ALSA plug-in [mocp]"

Answer (score 0):

Check `/proc/asound/cardX/stream0` to see which sample formats are supported, and which one is currently being used:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card2/stream0
Roland EDIROL UA-1A at usb-0000:0d:00.3-1, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 1
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 192
    Momentary freq = 44100 Hz (0x2c.199a)
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 44100
...
```